# undefined local variable or method `root_path'

Tags: ruby, rspec

после запуска bundle exec rspec spec/
получаю данные ошибки

```
Randomized with seed 46870
FFFF.......................FFFF

Failures:

  1) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::SignupPage:0x00000003f80428>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `signup_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::SignupPage:0x00000003f9dc80>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::ProfilePage:0x00000003fc3480>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User pages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPages::ProfilePage:0x00000004902fa0>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
     Failure/Error: visit root_path

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages:0x000000048bead0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Static pages Home page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages::HomePage:0x000000048dfb18>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages::HomePage::ItShouldBehaveLikeAllStaticPages:0x000000048e6288>
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 
     Failure/Error: before { visit root_path }

     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::StaticPages::HomePage::ItShouldBehaveLikeAllStaticPages:0x000000048e98e8>
     Shared Example Group: "all static pages" called from ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Deprecation Warnings:

Requiring `rspec/autorun` when running RSpec via the `rspec` command is deprecated. Called from /home/maddi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 0.27903 seconds (files took 2.62 seconds to load)
31 examples, 8 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:19 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:18 # User pages signup page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:44 # Static pages should have the right links on the layout
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:20 # Static pages Home page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:10 # Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:11 # Static pages Home page it should behave like all static pages 

Randomized with seed 46870
```

Содержимое Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '=2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'

gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4.2'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.3.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

содержимое routes:

```
SampleApp1::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users

  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

и содержимое user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

решило проблему добавление строчки
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
в файл spec/spec_helper.rb

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавление в файл `spec/requests/spechelper.rb`
строчки: `config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

```
########################################################################
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

end
```